# Find value in database between to values

Tags: mysql, python-3.4

I wan't to make a function that returns a Country based on a IP.
I have converted the IP to a decimal value, so mysql can make "Between". 
Below is what i got so fare.

```
def get():
     con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root',
     passwd='******', db='IP')
     ip_d = "16777221"
     with con:

         cur = con.cursor()
         return cur.execute("SELECT Land FROM IPaddresses where ip_d
         BETWEEN Start and End")
get()
```

Start and End are the first ip and end ip in a country, are also represented as a deciamal value.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL BETWEEN explained:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

You should change `Start` and `End` to some numeric parameters:

```
startValue=111222333
endValue=888999000

return cur.execute("SELECT Land FROM IPaddresses where ip_d
    BETWEEN {start} and {end}".format(start=startValue,end=EndValue))
```

Comment: I needs to scan througe the database, so it findes the country where ip_d is between Start and End